# django operational error when model contains created_at and updated_at datetime fields

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # on_deleting user, profile will also be deleted
    image = models.ImageField(default="profilepic.jpg",upload_to="profile_pictures")
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    anonymous = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

my model has been working just fine untill now. I recently added created_at and updated_at fields to the form. I deleted all the files in migration folder. did makemigrations and migrate to start fresh.

despite all this, i keep getting the error : **no such column: users_profile.created_at**

Comment: it wont help, you need to dropdb and createdb again.

Comment: Why `no such column: users_profile.created_at` when your model name is `Profile`? Look at this direction

Answer (score 0):

You've made changes on your model but you need to add "created_at" and "updated_at" to your schema fields.

Example:

```
userSchema = create_schema(Profile, fields=['user', 'image', 'dob', 'bio', 'anonymous', 'created_at', 'updated_at'])
```